# How to install font locally from web page

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Is there any way to install font from a webpage like display a button and if user click on this some font will install on local system. I don't know its is possible or not through JavaScript or any other client side.

Comment: this is possible in most cases, and the font file can be located using the developer tools, but it might involve copyright issues.

Comment: how it is possible? can you give some example>?

Comment: @AsadSiddiqui Jargo's not asking how to install a font that is being used on a webpage he/she's on, but how to make their own webpage automatically install a font for users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you describe it, no. You can easily hook up a button to trigger a *download* for the font (or any file, for that matter), but the user will then still have to install the font themselves after it has been downloaded to their computer.

The browser does not get to initiate that action in the Operating System: it would be **incredibly** insecure if it was allowed to, because fonts are very complicated bits of software, and you might be able to take advantage of a bug in one of the many font parsers. If you could make the browser "force" a font to be installed for a user, you would be able to do all sorts of bad stuff depending on how bad the bug was, from remote code execution to crashing their computer to even silently taking over their computer entirely.